# Docker image build getting stuck at "npm install" for ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, kubernetes

I am making a kubernetes cluster for my microservices application.
I am building the docker image and for some reason, it gets stuck @npm install step :

> GETS STUCK HERE :

```
$ docker build -t karanshreds/client .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  626.2kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> 3bf5a7d41d77
Step 2/7 : ENV CI=true
 ---> Running in 3ffe706d12a3
Removing intermediate container 3ffe706d12a3
 ---> bcd186e89d1b
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 4b68ea73ef58
emoving intermediate container 4b68ea73ef58
 ---> 2427bc0ae6e8
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 2d26f309fb4d
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in ce5043208676
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @types/testing-library__dom@7.5.0: This is a stub types definition. testing-library__dom provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
ENV CI=true
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./ 
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

It works when I use **node instead of node:alpine**. **But it creates an image of size 1GB+**. Which I obviously do not want.

> #NOTE: Just in case if you're wondering what my package.json files has :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you are saying you get an error, but i see no error in the logs from the docker build command, just a bunch of warning about some packages being deprecated, also you should try using multi stage docker builds and actually build the react app instead of using the dev version

Comment: I just edited it. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue is with running the `npm install` command, the logs seem to provide no reason to believe that there is actually something wrong in them, all i see are some warning messages about some packages being deprecated but not in fact errors. Either way, you said that it did work when you used `node` instead of `node:alpine`, which can help us.

Usually what you would want is: to build the app and have it running in separate docker layers. You can use multi-stage docker build for that purpose. This way you will have a separate environment in which you can build your app (`node` as required) and separate for running it, let's say minimal nginx. Below you can see an example of a single `Dockerfile` supporting the notion

```
# build environment
FROM node as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Thank you, this one was built really fast.